# Total sum by Unique ID using df.groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the data set I'm working on, each unique ID has a Total Pay. I've summed this Total pay up per ID by using

```
df['Total Courier Pay'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Total Pay'].transform(sum)
df
```

The output in the excel sheet looks like this:

[image]

I'm happy to keep all the columns shown but is there any way to clean it up so it looks more like this instead of having duplicate rows for each ID?:

```
ID      Total Courier Pay
1          5.1615
2          59.1075
3          7.4925
```

Is it possible to create a new sheet in the same workbook where it only displays the ID and Total Courier Pay?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: df['Total Courier Pay'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Total Pay'].agg(sum) ?

Comment: What Dani said. You specifically use transform when you want to keep the dataframe the same size! I think ```.apply()``` would also do what you want.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Hi Dani, thanks for your answer. Changing it from .transform to .agg doesn't seem to return the total pay anymore.

Comment: @HarryPlotter Hi, thanks for the answer but this is the same with .agg, it doesn't return the sum of the total courier pay into the column. It seems to only sum the Total Pay when I do .transform(sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Total Courier Pay'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Total Pay'].transform(sum)
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])[['ID','Total Courier Pay']]
```

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks for your answer. I had tried using df.drop_duplicates but I can still see duplicate IDs in the sheet.

Comment: My mistake subset should be ["ID"]. Try it now

Comment: It still shows duplicate IDs. 

What does the [['ID', 'Total Courier Pay']] behind the subset do?

Comment: It selects only the columns `ID` and `Total Courier Pay`. Are you printing `new_df`?

Comment: As in is the new_df showing on the excel sheet? If so, then no, it's not showing on the excel sheet. Otherwise, I've followed the line of code you've shared exactly.

Comment: What's the output you are getting? I could replicate it here and it works.

Comment: The output was exactly the same as the screenshot provided in the question. It seems to have worked when I added inplace=True. Thank you for your help anyway :)

Comment: Inplace argument means that instead of creating a new df you change it directly. It returns `None` are you sure you were printing `new_df` instead of `df`?

Comment: Can I just check that when you say to print new_df, you mean to type new_df into the line of the code or do I have to replace the new_df with something like df['Unique ID'] to make a new column? Sorry, I only started using Pandas yesterday.

Comment: You said you're saving your Dataframe to a excel format, i assume there's a line saving it into a file, instead of having this: `df.to_excel("output.xlsx")` you should have this: `new_df.to_excel("output.xlsx")`

Comment: Ah! I see what you meant by printing new_df now. Sorry, as I said I'm still new to this! Yes, your code now works as it opens it up in a new spreadsheet :D Thanks for your patience Pedro

Comment: Your welcome, if you need any more help just let me know.

Comment: So if I wanted to include all columns, would I have to do this: new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])[['ID', 'Name', 'Hours', 'Vehicle', 'Total Courier Pay']] or is there a way to include all columns without listing them all but still export to a new excel sheet

Comment: If you want all columns just remove `[['ID','Total Courier Pay']]` resulting in just `new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])`

Answer (score 1):

After some help from @Pedro Maia and reading some other forums, this seemed to work for me:

```
df.drop_duplicates('ID', inplace=True)
```

Thanks for the help :) - This will change the current excel sheet rather than create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, it seems that you want to create a separate DataFrame with only the 'ID' and 'Total Courier Pay'. In that case, you can do

```
total_pay_by_ID = (
    df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Total Pay']
      .sum()
      .rename(columns={'Total Pay': 'Total Courier Pay'})
)
```

> Is it possible to create a new sheet in the same workbook where it only displays the ID and Total Courier Pay?

To save it to a new sheet `'sheet_name'` of an existing excel file `'path/to/excel/file.xlsx'` you can do

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('path/to/excel/file.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
    total_pay_by_ID.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet_name')
```

Comment: Hi Harry, I'm trying to print a groupby set into new sheets. I just wanted to ask if it's necessary to have the `.rename`? I followed the example above but when I run it, no new sheets are created.

Comment: Example: `per_courier = (
    df.groupby(['ID'])['ID']
        .agg(sum)
)`

then I run `with pd.ExcelWriter('Path\file.xlsx, mode='a') as writer:
    per_courier.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Per Courier')`